# Neovim Nerd Tree Plugin: Shows EVERYTHING (Windows 10)

Tags: neovim

My nerd tree plugin shows EVERY folder and file in my C:/Users/(myusername) directory. It didnt do this before.

How can I change which directory it lists?

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker. Ideally with better wording.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/